# How can i export my web page to pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, itext

i use this tutorial :http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-ASPNet-Web-Page-with-images-to-PDF-using-ITextsharp.aspx 
for convert my page to pdf ,but when i run the project  i get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: RegisterForEventValidation can only be called
>   during Render();
>   how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the author of your tutorial suggests going to http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/RegisterForEventValidation-can-only-be-called-during-Render.aspx
to solve the problem